# Attempt to use Aurelia plugin causing 404 error in browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, jspm, aurelia

**UPDATE:**

My confusion is that I mistook Client Library for the term Plugin

Installing and using a library is documented here:

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I am trying to use firebase with a new aurelia app.

I found this documentation:

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/7

```
npm install -g aurelia-cli
au new APPNAME
cd APPNAME
jspm install firebase

// main.js
//... included default code omitted

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  //... etc
};

// SECURITY CREDENTIALS IN YOUR SOURCE CODE??????????
// Yes, I KNOW not to put secure credentials in my source code.
// This is just a silly learning app on my own development machine
// trying to learn how to use both Aurelia and Firebase.

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('resources')
    .plugin('firebase', firebaseConfig);

  //... included default code omitted
}
```

**au run --watch** loads fine

Load **http://localhost:9000** in my browser and in console this happens:

```
DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-templating-binding.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-binding.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-templating-resources.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-resources.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-event-aggregator.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-event-aggregator.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-history-browser.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-history-browser.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-templating-router.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-router.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin resources/index.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin resources/index.
vendor-bundle.js:13938 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin firebase.
http://localhost:9000/src/firebase.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor-bundle.js:1399 Unhandled rejection Error: Script error for "firebase"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3924:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:5491:36)
From previous event:
    at DefaultLoader.loadModule (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:13673:14)
    at _loadPlugin (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:12719:21)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:12712:16
From previous event:
    at loadPlugin (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:12711:75)
    at next (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:12972:20)
From previous event:
    at next (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:12972:56)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:12979:16
From previous event:
    at FrameworkConfiguration.apply (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:12964:44)
    at Aurelia.start (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:12581:23)
    at Object.configure (http://localhost:9000/scripts/app-bundle.js:93:13)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11485:22
From previous event:
    at config (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11480:48)
    at handleApp (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11471:12)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11504:13
From previous event:
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11502:40
From previous event:
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11501:29
From previous event:
    at run (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11497:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11524:3)
    at Object.execCb (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:5449:33)
    at Module.check (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4637:51)
    at Module.enable (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4929:22)
    at Object.enable (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:5310:39)
    at Module.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4914:33)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3890:23
    at each (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3815:31)
    at Module.enable (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4866:17)
    at Module.init (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4542:26)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:5213:36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used the Aurelia-CLI, and that there is no `install` command yet (ough), you have to add manually what you install through JSPM or NPM to `aurelia_project/aurelia.json`. In your case, add to the `dependencies` object the following:

```
{
    "name": "firebase",
    "path": "../jspm_modules/github/firebase/",
    "main": "firebase"
}
```

> This did not work

### My recommendations

These are totally personal from my experience with Aurelia and the CLI.

#### You want to use JSPM

[Download](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation) and use the skeletons, and not the CLI.

#### You want to use the CLI

Download your 3rd party libraries preferably from NPM, and include them in your `aurelia.json` following [the documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6).
If you download from GitHub, place all your libraries in the same folder and update the `aurelia.json` file, just like you would do with an NPM package.

Comment: Thank you. So far this seems like the right way to go, however I am having trouble getting it to work so far.

Where I am right now is the path and main needs to be updated:

    "path": "../jspm_packages/github/firebase",
    "main": "firebase-bower@3.6.4"

However now when I run au run it seems to be trying to use the path in package.json?

 code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'github:firebase/firebase-bower@3.6.4/firebase.js',

It seems to have the fileName right...

  fileName: '/Users/joemsak/work/todo/jspm_packages/github/firebase/firebase-bower@3.6.4.js' }

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot the `github` part. Is it working with this updated path? If not, did the error message change?

Comment: hey @nicovank I really appreciate your help. See my latest edits in the above comment.

Comment: And I just want to comment that I used the aurelia-cli because the home page demo video suggests to do this. And then I found plugin documentation as linked in my question. Based on my experience, is there any documentation edit I can make and send as a PR somewhere to help?

Comment: I am going to try to reproduce this issue (not with firebase but with any JSPM package), to see how it behaves. I usually use only NPM packages when using the CLI.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your time. I used npm initially, but when that didn't work, the docs I found suggested to use jspm so I tried that instead. I also found people online saying to do the command like this "jspm install npm:LIBNAME" but that didn't help either :^)

Comment: I could not reproduce the errors yet, I will give it more time later. I updated my answer with how I usually run my projects. If ever you find a solution, keep me posted!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130727/discussion-between-joe-sak-and-nicovank).